# Is there an equivalent program to SyncBackPro for Linux?

Tags: linux, backup

We are migrating to Linux however one of the many programs we use daily is SyncBackPro. Is there a equivalent GUI application that supports command line synxtax?

Comment: Check review, choose the one you like more http://www.techdrivein.com/2010/12/top-5-open-source-backup-software-for.html

Comment: Which features do you require?

Comment: @kamae - I would like to have all the features of SyncBackPro

Comment: @Artem Koshelev - Thanks however they seem to lack the features found on SyncBackPro e.g. the ability to simulate the mirroring or synchronization process whereby it gives you a list of changes to expect before committing them.